# How can I create a C++ class that accepts function pointers with different signatures?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am relatively new to C++ and I am working on a personal project for practicing where I need to create a class that can take function pointers with different signatures.

The idea is that each instance of the class will store a pointer to a specific function and can call that function whenever I want.

To give a better idea of what I want, let me explain with a little bit more detail what I am trying to do. The project I am working on is a very basic console game and the object I am trying to create is an object that would store details on each location the player can access in the game.

**(DISCLAIMER: I know that most of what I describe later is probably an overkill for a basic console game. I can easily make the whole game in a couple of files using just simple functions and I know how to do that. But the idea here is that I wanted to practice more advanced C++ techniques without having to figure out a complex project. So, since I know how to make a basic console game, I thought it would be a good idea to try and figure out how to achieve the same result but with more advanced techniques)**

One of the details that I think should be stored is what happens in each location, basically the text that is output to the screen describing what happens and prompting the user to take action.

Since this would be different for each location, I can't just declare and implement a function in the class.

One way of solving this issue is to create a base class with a virtual function and then implement this function in a series of derived classes, each defining a new location.

The problem I have with this approach is that it makes each location a class that can be inherited further and instanced, which I don't need as I will only have 1 instance of each location.

I can of course just create 1 instance of the class, but I wanted to see if there is a way to avoid having to create separate classes for each location.

This why I started thinking of function pointers.

Now, I know I can declare a function pointer and initialise it in a class like that:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test(void (*p)())
            : print{p}
        {}
    private:
        void (*print)();
};
```

That works fine as long as the function returns void and accepts no arguments.

So, I thought maybe I can do that with a template:

```
template <typename Function>
class Test
{
    public:
        Test(Function *p)
            : print{p}
        {}
        Function *print;
};
```

This actually works well. I can now have a class that accepts different functions with different return types.

I can create instances of the class in the following way:

```
void print();

Test<void ()> a {print};
```

However, I have one problem with this approach. Because it is a class template, I can't have a pointer that I want to use to point to instances of Test class regardless of the function that is passed to them.

For instance, if I declare the following pointer:

```
Test<void ()> *b = &a;
```

There is no way to re-assign that pointer to another instance of Test class unless the function pointer passed to it also returns void and accepts no arguments. Otherwise, I have to create a new pointer.

Is there a way to avoid that? Is there a better way of achieving what I am looking for than using function pointers?

Thank you very much and sorry for the long message.

Comment: Why would the type be different for different locations?

Comment: @user253751: Because the virtual function would need to differ. The logic makes sense; the typical implementation of virtual functions stores a function pointer in a table. That's a tiny overhead, but it's not needed here. Yet, I'd say that the overhead is still worth it because it allows you to use standard C++ from your textbook.

Comment: Assuming that you somehow want to call your functions via one pointer by any chance, I  believe you have to make all your functions with same return type. They also have to have the same signature for the call but you could bind additional parameters to your functions early. A tool for this is [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which can bind plain functions as well as objects with member functions and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). The latter provide the other tool to make adapters (for binding additional arguments).

Comment: Of course, a lambda could also adapt to a function with a non-matching return type. However, if you write these functions by yourself I don't see why you have to have different return types if the actual use case (calling via a unique function pointer) doesn't have any purpose for this.

Comment: Most likely, the functoins won't have different return types. But since I am practising, I am trying to imagine a scenario where they might and trying to find a way to address it.

Comment: @MSalters that makes no sense. If your functions have different types, *how do you call them* when they all have different types? Whenever you call a function the compiler has to know the type of the function you are calling.

Comment: It is possible to do it with templates and function pointers. You can have a function in the class that calls the pointer which would be passed as a template argument. If you check my question, the Test template class already does this. You can create different instances of it with different functions. The one problem I have with it as I said is that I can't declare a pointer that can point to these different instances.

Comment: If each function pointer is the _thing to do at a particular location_, they should all have the same interface: probably taking a reference to the game state and returning the new location, if it changes. It's basically a normal finite state machine. Unless you have a concrete reason to think they should take different arguments in the first place?

Comment: As I said, at the moment, all the functions have the same return types. But since I am doing all of this for educational purposes, I am just trying to think of different scenarios and see how I can approach them. So, I wanted to see what can I do if I had a reason to have the each game location using a function that have different return types.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no way to re-assign that pointer to another instance of Test class unless the function pointer passed to it also returns void and accepts no arguments.

And how would you expect that to work? Each `Test` has a different signature for its `print` method. In the example below, if you assigned `action2` to `action1`, then how would it know what to pass to the print function?

```
void fun1() {}
void fun2(int) {}

void test() {
  Test<void()> action1= &fun1;
  action1.print();
  Test<void(int)> action2= &fun2;
  action2.print(42);
}
```

What you want is really simple, thanks to improvements in C++11: `std::function<void()>`.

Whenever you need to pass some arguments to the function, you'd use a lambda, potentially with captures:

```
#include <functional>

void fun1() {}
void fun2(int) {}

using Action = std::function<void()>;

int main() {
  class MyObject { public: void doSomething() {} } obj;

  Action action1;
  action1 = fun1;
  action1 = []{ fun2(42); };
  action1 = [&obj]{ obj.doSomething(); }; // obj captured by reference
}
```

So that's pretty much what you should do.

Now of course you may ask "hey, but what if I wanted to implement something like `std::function` myself"? It's not a trivial task, if you want to get full functionality of `std::function`, including small object optimization (i.e. `std::function` usually doesn't allocate unless the functor it wraps is "big").

> I wanted to see what can I do if I had a reason to have the each game location using a function that have different return types.

You chose to use a common abstraction, i.e. some class (like `Action`) that you can always call the same way, and get to do various things. So, what would you like the following code to do?

```
Action someAction;
int result = someAction();
std::string result = someAction();
```

Now suppose that e.g. `someAction` has captured a `void()` function. What should the code that assigns the "result" to an integer or a string do? And how would you protect from mistakes, e.g. if you really wanted `someAction()` to return an int, but you accidentally used one that returns nothing?

Remember that *the compiler has to generate code for all of the sites where you call `someAction`*, so it needs to know what to do ahead of time, even if you may otherwise ensure that no "incorrect" calls are made.

You could implement a custom `Action` class on top of `std::function` that could support `std::optional<ResultType>` instead of `ResultType`. That way, if the actual result of the functor wrapped in `Action` was convertible to that `ResultType`, you'd get a non-null optional, otherwise the optional would be null. And the list of supported result types would need to be pre-determined, i.e. the compiler wouldn't be able to dynamically add them, but adding a new type should amount to passing an additional type as a template argument, so it'd be easy to support quite many types.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Unslander. Regarding the part you quoted, I didn't expect it to work. I was just stating that it doesn't work and that I need something to achieve what I am looking for. I will give std::function a try and see if I can do what I want to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: What I was looking to do is the part you discussed at the end of the post. Seeing if it is possible to get `Action` to accept functions with different return types. But it makes sense that it might be hard to safeguard it against errors, so even if I can do it, it might not be the best idea. I will have to look into `std::function` a bit more to try the optional `ResultType` solution you suggested.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSaid The biggest problem I see is that you're trying to override C++'s static typing to run some dynamic typing layer. That usually implies that the design that prompts this is unidiomatic and needs to be rethought. If the intent is to return variants, you should return variants, but that is most in place in framework code or when using a framework that needs such flexibility. `std::variant` or Qt's `QVariant` would be worth considering then.

Comment: As I said, since I am realtively new to C++, I am just trying to figure out what can and cannot be done. It gives me a better understanding of the language. What you say makes sense though. I will probably won't need something that return variants for most of the things I would like to do with C++. I definitely won't need it now, at least. Thank you for your input.